# Should I be worried about dog coughing (with heart murmur and congestive heart failure)?

Tags: dogs, health, heart-health

My dog has had a heart murmur since birth. He is now nine years old and is a Chihuahua. He has the beginnings of congestive heart failure since he is getting some fluid in his lungs. He is currently on Lasix 20 mg two times a day. He still gets the cough/choking after being at rest for a period of time. I am assuming this is somewhat typical as I'm sure the the lasix will not completely get rid of this. My question is how bad is it for the dog to be coughing like this? It is somewhat worrisome as it almost seems like he is choking. He seems fine afterwards. It's just so frustrating that there is nothing I can really do for him.

Answer (score 3):

Since you say that your dog has the beginnings of congestive heart failure, I assume you've been to a vet recently to get this diagnosis, it's ultimately a terminal condition, and that coughing/choking is a known symptom of his condition. I know nothing about congestive heart failure specifically, but I suggest you call the vet, discuss the frequency of the coughing, and ask if you should bring the dog in. The vet may be able to suggest something over the phone (e.g. a change in the dosage).

If you haven't been to a vet recently, or if the coughing has become more frequent or sounds different than it used to, then I would take the dog in to the vet.

You can also ask the vet for advice on what to expect as the condition progresses.

Also, I suggest you take note of what activities your dog still enjoys, and what makes him happy. This will help you decide if and when it's time for euthanasia. Best of luck to you and your dog.

Comment: Have been to the vet recently. Talked to him today actually and everything I described to him is  as "normal" as it gets at this stage. I will continue to watch him closely and will eventually put him on VetMedin.